# node js , imap read unseen message to get otp

Tags: node.js, email, bots, puppeteer, imap

this first time using IMAP, so I fetched unread messages to get OTP (read the message then get the last 7 strings that will be my otp) and filled in input using puppeteer
so the code works just fine but I have an issue I get 2 buffer values
1st is ''<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//E''
then the second message body that only what I need, because   puppeteer will write 2 values (otp+ 1st buffer value)
so how to get only the message body to get otp only

`

```
            var imap = new Imap({
            user: email,
            password: authPassword,

            host: "imap.gmail.com", 
            port: 993,
            tls: true,
            connTimeout: 10000, 
            authTimeout: 5000, 
            debug: console.log, 
            tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
            mailbox: "INBOX", 
            searchFilter: ["UNSEEN", "FLAGGED"], 
            markSeen: true, 
            fetchUnreadOnStart: true, 
            mailParserOptions: { streamAttachments: true },
            attachments: true,  
            attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } 
          });

          function openInbox(cb) {
            imap.openBox('INBOX', false, cb);
          }

          imap.once('ready',  function () {
            openInbox(function (err, box) {
              if (err) throw err;
              imap.search(['UNSEEN', ['SUBJECT', 'Login OTP']], function (err, results) {
                //1st otp 'Login OTP'
                //2nd otp 'OTP Confirmation'
                if (err) throw err;
                var f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: '1', markSeen: true });
                f.on('message', function (msg, seqno) {
          
                  msg.on('body', function (stream, info) {
                    stream.on('data',async function (chunk) {
                      console.log('chunk is '+chunk);
                      buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
                      console.log("BUFFER is" + buffer)
                      const msg1 = convert(buffer, {
                        wordwrap: 130
                      });
                      console.log('msg1 ' +msg1);
                      //gmail message buddy

                      //Hi,
                      //We need to make sure you are human. Please verify your email by below OTP.       OTP - 5391726
                        const otp1 = msg1.substr(msg1.length - 8)
                      
                      console.log('otp ' +otp1);
                      await  page.focus("#al_login > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input"); 
                      await page.keyboard.type(otp1);


                    })

                  });
          
                });
                // f.once('error', function (err) {
                //   // console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
                // });
                f.once('end', function () {
                  console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
                  imap.end();
                });
              });
            });
          });

          imap.once('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          });

          imap.once('end', function () {
            console.log('Connection ended');
          });

          imap.connect();
```

`

log:

```
BUFFER is<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//E
msg1 DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//E
otp ional//E

msg1 Date : 2023-01-20   SYSTEM GENERATED VERIFICATION CODE   Hi,
We need to make sure you are human. Please verify your email by below OTP.   OTP - 2738965

otp 2738965
```

this is my code above

Answer (score 0):

i fix it by creating HTML file using node js "FS" and then reading it and getting OTP this is the best solution for me cuz I don't have time.